# How can I run an X server on cloud9?

Tags: server, 16.04, xorg, cloud, lxde

I need to install and run an X server on [Cloud9](http://c9.io). I've tried everything I know but nothing works.

When I ran `apt-get install lxde xinit` and then `xinit` it gave me an error log ending with:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
          at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The log file does not give any extra insight about why it fails. Is this Cloud9-specific or am I doing something wrong? How can I run an X server on Cloud9?

**EDIT:**

As per @psiphi75's comment I tried cloud9-vnc. It installed properly but failed at `./run.sh`:

```
VNC client running at https:///vnc.html
Error: Format string '/opt/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900 -- listen %(ENV_PORT)s' for 'command' contains names which cannot be expanded
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Comment: Have you tried [Cloud9 VNC](https://c9.io/angryrock/cloud9-vnc)?

Comment: I don't know.  But running X11 directly in Cloud9 seems unfeasible to me, X11 is a graphical system used by Linux/Unix that needs access to hardware, either directly or via the network.  Cloud9 is stuck in the browser, so doesn't provide the infrastructure for X11. Here is the github repo for [Cloud VNC](https://github.com/noobkilervip/cloud9-vnc).